# Sequence alignment obtaining all sequences

Tags: algorithm, alignment, dynamic-programming, sequence-alignment

I've been trying to do some sequence alignment with the following sequences:

`ggaatggmeeff`

`gatge`

Im finding it difficult to understand how you determine the final alignment sequences. I am unsure if this is correct. Been reading up online regarding this but still finding myself confused. Would appreciate any insight on this.

[image]

Comment: Your attempt is fine and corresponds to `.g.at.g..e..` <-> `ggaatggmeeff`

Comment: @Stef Thanks for the reply! How might I obtain all the possible alignment sequences. This is something that confuses me. The way I understand it is that you trace back based on the largest number of the 3 that surround the current cell but this results in the output above.